# How to use shortcuts for tools instead of actions in Blender 2.8

Tags: shortcut

I'm having some problem with the way blender handle the shortcuts. When I use a shortcut for a tool, like the extrusion one, for example, it immediately execute extrusion, instead of just selecting the tool.

I managed to bypass it by clicking in each option at the quick tools menu and reinserting the shortcuts, but apparently I have to do that for each blender mode. Is there a option I'm missing in the preferences or maybe a plugin to make Blender behave differently?